# Simple Screen Recorder recordes only audio

Tags: video

I have been using Simple Screen Recorder for several months. Installed on PC from Ubuntu list. Worked great until suddenly it recorded only the audio. Video sources have been camera (AVI), youtube, FsTV.org (live news). Now all theses sources record just the audio. Always used default settings.

System is desktop Ubuntu 20.04. echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE says I'm using wayland. I've search for how to change but nothing seems to work or apply. I'm not fluent in terminal but I can enter commands.
Thanks, John.

Comment: Have you tried any other screen recorders like Kazam?

Comment: Also, are you using Wayland or X11? The description says that it's for X11 and OpenGL. Try logging in to an X11 or Xorg session instead of Wayland to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: this shows how to change the session: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop

Comment: It didn't work with X11 either.

Comment: Maybe your user has to be in a certain group?